# why there is iterator for std::vector

Tags: css, vector, iterator

Why there is need for vector to have iterator?

Vector have no base type, its size is known and there is a way to get any element. On top of that vector is continious and there are no pelalty to random access any element.

Probably I am wrong, I did not saw any function or method that accepts iterator as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector` have iterator in order to:

- be a valid STL container
- be able to pass the iterator to several functions that uses iterators instead of containers itself.
- be able to use new style `for`.